# LibGDX RPG walking animation

Tags: android, animation, libgdx

I've been trying to nail down a walking animation with libGDX.  I'm making an RPG with the character that can move up, down, left, and right.  I have this movement in a spritesheet.  I've been following a youtube tutorial called Java Tiled Map Game which can be found here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qik60F5I6J4

He does a better job then some of explaining what the code does but he glosses over the part where he gets his character to do a walking animation (by which I mean he doesn't show it at all).

I then moved to the tutorial found here: http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-tutorial-part-2-animation/

But this tutorial tells exactly what needs to be done in regular words and then just gives a block of code.  I already know what I need to do in regular words but I'm not trying to learn english but programming which is a completely different language.  I'm sure I could copy and paste that code and edit it to do what I need but I wouldn't understand HOW it works only THAT it works.  I want to know the how of it all.  I'm new to libGDX and this is my first RPG game.  I really want learn how to do it myself instead of relying on others.

My question is simply this:  Do you know of a tutorial which shows and (more importantly) explains how to do a simple walking animation?  I'm hoping you can supply one for me.

Comment: So are you telling that you want to do animation from scratch without using the tools provided by libGDX?

Comment: No.  I want to use libgdx to do as much as possible I just can't find a good tutorial on using the animation framework in it.  Can you help me by pointing me to one?

Comment: Are you using 2d animation or on a 3d character?

Comment: Did you check out the official documentation; https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SpriteAnimation ? It is a pretty concise tutorial in itself, but still leaves enough room to make your own adaptation.

Comment: 2d animation is what I am attempting.

Comment: Questions asking for a list of resources or questions where every answer could be equally valid (such as asking for a tutorial or tutorials) aren't considered on-topic here; please see the [help]. Consider editing your question to reformulate your query into a specific, practical question that could be objectively answered (pre-emptively, "how do I implement 2D animation" is going to be too broad, but asking about specific sub-problems you're running into in such an implementation would be more reasonable).